# Find step between two values in C

Tags: c, math

The code i'm looking for is the following :

We have a source number `100`, a destination number, `50` and we have `10` steps.
100 ----> 50 in 10 steps.

How can i find the value X, corresponding to `the number i have to sub` to 100, 10  times to have 50. I found : `dest*steps/src` but didn't work...

Regards.

Comment: Can't you simply use the for loops as they are intended? As in `for (X = 100; X >= 50; X = X - 10) /* code */;`

Comment: Also it's more like `dest - i * step`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's as simple as this

```
X = (src-dest)/NumOfSteps
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int source = 100;
int dest = 50;

int numSteps = 0

do {
    source -= 10;
    ++numSteps;
} while (source > dest);

printf("Subtracted 10, %d times, from %d to reach %d.", numSteps, source, dest);
```